# Uploading image data from CKEditor 5 to Firebase Storage creates a malformed image

Tags: ckeditor, buffer, firebase-storage, form-data, ckeditor5

I'm uploading form data containing an image using an `XHRHttpRequest` with CKEditor 5. I'm receiving the `Buffer` correctly, and I've retrieved the content type successfully:

```js
const data = new FormData
data.append('upload', fileObject)
myXhrHttpRequest.send(data)
```

I retrieve the image data by accessing the body of the HTTP POST request (a `Buffer`), and then I upload it to Firebase Storage:

```js
app.post('/save-image', async ({ query: { imageId, contentType }, body: data }, res) => {
  storage
    .file(`images/${id}`)
    .save(data, {
        public: true,
        metadata: {
            contentType,
            metadata: {
                firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: token
            }
        }
     })

   // send back results, etc...
})
```

Unfortunately, the image is corrupt. Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong? This is an example of one of the uploaded images:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/memorize-ai.appspot.com/o/deck-assets%2Fsample_deck_id%2FHq7vZ8oEgFqlLdSfWYBl?alt=media&token=cfa99560-5618-48e1-8772-4ffd9d45f789

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Can you tell me if you've found the answer so far? Thank you very much 

Comment: @jmpp Are you doing this on iOS?

Comment: @KenMueller Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Jason Yes I did. On iOS, you need to make a custom CKEditor upload adapter that sends over the data to your server in base64. I don't know why you can't send normal binary data, but base64 works perfectly.